# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Documents.Open("C:\\doc.doc") not open

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, interop

When i trying to open the document (.doc or .docx) instance of document is NULL.

```
Application wordApplication = new Application();
wordApplication.Visible = false;
Document wordDocument =  wordApplication.Documents.Open("C:\\doc.doc");
```

And why is wordApplication.Documents.Count equal of zero?

(Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, MS Office 2010 x64)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/architecturegeneral/thread/0f5448a7-72ed-4f16-8b87-922b71892e07) helped me several  years ago.

**Inlined**

There are several suggested answers, I tried the second one and it solved my problem. But I'm inlining all of them here/.

**1-st approach:** try to create a  new "Desktop" directory inside of "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\"

**2-nd:** you must change the identity of word component in `windows\System32\comexp.msc` to be interactive user instead of launching user.

**3-rd:**
0. Set the DCOM Config Setting for "Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 Document"
    (Open the properties > Identity Tab > Select "The interative User"
    Secutiry Tab > Lanuch and Acctivation Permissions > Add `Network Serivce`

1. Save the settings
2. Open your Virtual directory in IIS
3. Select the Virtual directory
4. Select "Authentication".
5. Edit anonymous authentication
6. Dialog box will get opened > click on set >  admin user (any admin user is good)

Comment: Can you inline any of that content? MS is very good at changing their link structure every few years, leading to dead links.

Comment: option 1 worked for me on server 2012 with office 2010